# Reading multiple lines of doubles with fscanf

Tags: c, double, scanf

I have an input file which contains six doubles on every line, which I would like to be read by fscanf. However, after reading the numbers from the input file, all stored values are zero. For example:

Input:

```
8.260358155 0.217414463 0.079918794 -0.068255156 -0.124913458 0.821136998
0.095921056 0.878265878 1.099486349  0.766342809  1.918243674 0.476907831
1.050441605 8.451442631 0.945819695 -0.440024089 -1.149013541 0.374284191
```

Code:

```
    double r[NMAX][3];
    double rv[NMAX][3];
    int nAtom = 3;
    int n;
    FILE *loadFile = fopen(LoadName,"r");
    if (loadFile == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: can't open loadFile\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(loadFile,"%d",&nAtom);
    for (n=0; n<nAtom; ++n){
        fscanf(loadFile, "%f %f %f %f %f %f",
               &r[n][0],&r[n][1],&r[n][2],&rv[n][0],&rv[n][1],&rv[n][2]);
    }

    fclose(loadFile);

    for (n=0; n<nAtom; ++n){
        printf("%12.9f %12.9f %12.9f %12.9f %12.9f %12.9f\n",
                r[n][0],r[n][1],r[n][2],rv[n][0],rv[n][1],rv[n][2]);
    }
```

Output:

```
0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
```

Could anyone say what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `fscanf(loadFile, "%f %f %f %f %f %f",...`  use `%lf` for `double`.

Comment: Always check the function return value of those like `fscanf` so you know the correct number of fields were read and converted.  `if (6 != fscanf(....`

Comment: Functions from the `printf` family promote `float` to `double`, so they treat `%f` and `%lf` in the same manner (expecting an 8-byte argument). These format specifiers (`%f` and `%lf`) are distinguishable only when used in functions from the `scanf` family.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, Thanks a lot! Just one tiny problem remaining: The first double gets printed as 0.260358155 instead of 8.260358155.

Comment: Because of `fscanf(loadFile,"%d",&nAtom);` which does not seem to be present in the file. It reads the `8` and stops at the `.`

Comment: @Abenthy `//fscanf(loadFile,"%d",&nAtom);`

Comment: Sorry that line was supposed to be removed, my bad.
Thank you all a lot!

Comment: It's a mystery to me why only 3 rows of the array were printed, not 8!

Answer (score 1):

As @BLUEPIXY says in the comments, you're telling `fscanf` to parse your input values as `float`s, but having it put them into `double`s.  You could fix this by either (as suggested) use `%lf` to tell `fscanf` you're filling doubles, or declare `r` and `rv` to be arrays of `float`s.

Compilers are pretty good about warning of such things, if you ask them nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your fscanf should look like :

```
fscanf(loadFile, "%lf %lf %f %lf %lf %lf",&r[n][0],&r[n][1],&r[n][2],&rv[n][0],&rv[n][1],&rv[n][2]);
```

Then delete the line

```
 fscanf(loadFile,"%d",&nAtom);
```

Comment: The `\n` is not necessary.

Comment: Why is that ? There will be a \n after the 6 double values.

Comment: I suggest  you try it, to find out.

Comment: `fscanf` consumes leading white-space for format types `%d` and `%f` and `%s` but not for `%c` (unless that last has a space in the format like `" %c"`).

Comment: `"\n"` does not simple consume a single `'\n'`.  `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `" "` and other white-space variations all do the exact same thing: consume 0 or more white-spaces and continue consuming until a non-white-space is found (which is put back into `loadFile`) or `EOF` reached.  This directive never fails.